# MongoMapper near with maxDistance - Mongo::OperationFailure: geo values have to be numbers:

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, mongomapper

I'm trying to encapsulate a near query with a maxDistance in a MongoMapper backed model.

I must be doing something silly in my query syntax.

Model

```
class Site
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :id, Integer 
  key :name, String
  key :location, Array
  ensure_index [[:location, '2d']]


  def self.nearest(center_point, range)
    where(:location => {'$near' => center_point, '$maxDistance' => range}).all
  end

end
```

Trying to get everything within 200 miles of a point...

> > Site.nearest([-122.0,44.0],200)

```
> Mongo::OperationFailure: geo values have to be numbers: {
> $maxDistance: 200, $near: [ -122.0, 44.0 ] }  from
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongo-1.6.1/lib/mongo/cursor.rb:144:in
> `next'    from
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongo-1.6.1/lib/mongo/cursor.rb:290:in
> `each'    from
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongo-1.6.1/lib/mongo/cursor.rb:308:in
> `to_a'    from
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongo-1.6.1/lib/mongo/cursor.rb:308:in
> `to_a'    from
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/plucky-0.4.4/lib/plucky/query.rb:74:in
> `all'     from /Users/nick/Code/web/map/app/models/site.rb:40:in
> `nearest'     from (irb):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing it's actually a data problem or index problem, your query looks correct.

See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing ... MaxDistance of 200 may be too large:

> By default, the index assumes you are indexing longitude/latitude and is thus configured for a [-180..180) value range.
>
> The distance unit is the same as in your coordinate system.

Also try `Site.distinct(:location)` and look for any non-numeric data. (or `Site.query.distinct(:location)` if you're not on MM 0.11.1).

Hint: If you want to see what a query is going to look like when it hits MongoDB, add `.criteria.to_hash`:

```
Site.where(:location => {'$near' => center_point, '$maxDistance' => range}).criteria.to_hash
# =>
{
  :location=> {
    "$near"        => [-122.0, 44.0],
    "$maxDistance" => 200
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You may have run into [this bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1990) that requires `$near` and `$maxDistance` to be ordered with `$maxDistance` first.

In any case, I found this question because I was getting `OperationFailure: database error: geo values have to be number` when using PyMongo, and swapping the order fixed it.

Comment: This fix worked for me too. Thanks for saving me some time on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution [for this one](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-292?focusedCommentId=66774&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-66774)

```
{'location' : SON([('$near', [55.55632, 25.13522]), ('$maxDistance', 0.01)])})
```

Answer (score 0):

got this error with datas stored in session ( different contest, php + zf2) : a floatval(lat), floatval(lon) solved the issue :)
I'm posting it in case somebody needs it :)