# MongoDB Performance on MongoLab for Geospacial Queries

Tags: performance, mongodb, geospatial, mlab

I have a collection of places with more then 400,000 documents. I am trying to do geospacial queries but they always seem to timeout. 
From the MongoLab interface I do a search:

```
{ "location": {"$near": [ 38, -122 ] } }
```

And the page just times out.

Also ran this command thru my console:

```
db.runCommand({geoNear: "places", near: [50,50], num:10})
```

And it did succeed but took something like 5 minutes to complete.

I do have a Geospatial Index on location.

```
location    { "location" : "2d"}
```

Is it just impossible to do geospacial queries on such big collections (quite small for a MongoDB collection after all)?

EDIT: MongoLab personally contacted me regarding this problem. It seems there are some issues with my db such as many places not having any coords yet. Also I discovered that using maxDistance accelerates the queries dramatically, which brings me back to this morning's question here : [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13349430/yii-emongodocuments-near-queries-ignoring-maxdistance)

Comment: That should be a quick query unless you're really tight on memory.  Does `explain` show that your index is being used?

Comment: @JohnnyHK explain is not supported for anything else the find queries.  :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mongolabs techs have pointed out to me that having a lot of longitude latiudes set to 0,0 and NOT using a maxDistance was what was slowing things down. Adding the maxDistance worked like a charm..

So thanks again to the guy's at Mongolabs.